# Solution of second order DE as a ratio of sinh

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following second order DE:

$\xi'' - k^2\xi = 0 $

$\xi(a) = 0$

I've managed to bring it as far as $\xi = -c_2[e^{k(x-2a)}+e^{-kx}]$, by writing the solution as $\xi = c_1e^{kx}+c_2e^{-kx}$, using the given condition and solving for $c_1$.

The problem is, my book gives the solution as $\xi = c\frac{sinh[k(a-x)]}{sinh(ka)}$.

I guess it's not a difficult problem, but I just don't see it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator is just a constant

$$\xi = c\frac{\sinh[k(a-x)]}{\sinh(ka)}=K{\sinh[k(a-x)]}$$

Then mutliply by $e^{-ka}$ and $\sinh(x)=\dfrac {e^x-e^{-x}}2$

$$\xi =\frac R2({e^{[k(a-x)]}-e^{-ka+kx}})e^{-ka}$$

$$\xi =\frac R2({e^{-kx}-e^{-2ka+kx}})$$
Substitute $\frac R2=C$
$$\xi =-C(e^{k(x-2a)}\color{red}{-{e^{-kx}}})$$

Are you sure you don't have a sign mistake somewhere ?

Comment: You're right, should've been a "-" sign before the second exponential in my solution. Thanks for pointing this out! So it seems the results are equivalent, but I still have no idea how one would ever think of getting to the one in the book.

Comment: @Bogdan_C  your answer is correct except for the sign...so it dosent matter what the book says as long as your answer is correct...You can keep the exponential in the solution or use hyperbolic function dosent really matter...It's just for convenience..